# Next js Link - Navigation reload my complete page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, routes

[image: Header Page]

When i change page to about it reload the browser I dont want to reload page when Link to another page i use src structure here with typescript i remove all the extension but still give same issue i also use without src structure but same issue
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing the wrong `Link` component, you have to import `Link` from `next/link` instead of the one from mui package:

```js
import Link from 'next/link';
```

[see docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/link)